# How to fix "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" in a function in React (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got the following warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `TabContext`. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
> in TabForGroupInList (at Product.tsx:148)
> in TabContext (at Product.tsx:144)

Here it is the render method of `TabContext`:

```
export default function TabContext(props: any) {

  const selectedTabId = useSelector((state:any) => state.selectedTabId[props.id]);
...

    return (
        <>
          {props.tabContent(selectedTabId, onChangeHandler)}
        </>
    );
```

And here `TabContext` is called:

```
export default function Product() {

    const iter = (node: any, name: string) => {
        let c = child(node, name);
        let result: any = [];
        c.items.forEach(
            (e: any) => result.push(nodes[e])
        );
        return result;
    }


return (
 <>
  <TabContext id={id(rootNode, 'Multi_Page1')} tabContent ={(selectedTabId:any, 
  changeHandler:any)=>(

     <Tabs value={selectedTabId} changeHandler={changeHandler}>
        {iter(rootNode, 'Multi_Page1').map((Multi__Page1: any, index: number) => { return (
         <TabForGroupInList value={Multi__Page1.id} id={Multi__Page1.id} tabId={rootNode.id} />  
          )})}
     </Tabs>
 </>
)
}
```

I need to find a way to iterate thru `props.tabContent()` (`TabContext`), in order to get the different `tabId` props (`TabForGroupInList`) as a `key` in the render method of `TabContext`, but `props.tabContent()` is not an array, it is a function and I cannot use `map()`. Or is there any other way to get unique keys from `props.tabContent()`?

Comment: I think this is telling you that you need `key`s on the `TabForGroupInList` items that are in your `Product` renderer (e.g. you *are* using `map` there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `key={index}` or any unique identifier to your `TabForGroupInList` component.

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. It's quite often to see the key prop when we are iterating an array with methods like map ([source](https://meganslo.medium.com/why-is-reacts-key-prop-important-b6bd51124270#:%7E:text=Keys%20help%20React%20identify%20which,array%20with%20methods%20like%20map%20.))

The key prop is available in every React component you create out of the box